# why structured menu cannot be rendered in html template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i would like to make a structure database for a restaurant menu without using mptt or django-tree. here is my **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
class Menu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=24, unique=True, verbose_name='menu name')
    #slug = models.SlugField(max_length=24, unique=True, help_text='The slug is the URL friendly version of the menu name, so that this can be accessed at a URL like mysite.com/menus/dinner/.')
    additional_text = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True, help_text='Any additional text that the menu might need, i.e. Served between 11:00am and 4:00pm.')
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, help_text='The order of the menu determines where this menu appears alongside other menus.')
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name', 'order']

class MenuCategory(models.Model):
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.CASCADE,help_text='The menus that this category belongs to, i.e. \'Lunch\'.') 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name='menu category name')
    additional_text = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True, help_text='The additional text is any bit of related information to go along with a menu category, i.e. the \'Pasta\' category might have details that say \'All entrees come with salad and bread\'.')
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text='The order is the order that this category should appear in when rendered on the templates.')
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name='menu category'
        verbose_name_plural='menu categories'
        ordering = ['order', 'name']
    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class MenuItem(models.Model):
    CLASSIFICATION_CHOICES = (
        ('neither', 'Neither'),
        ('vegan', 'Vegan'),
        ('vegetarian', 'Vegetarian'),
    )
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=48, help_text='Name of the item on the menu.')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True, help_text='The description is a simple text description of the menu item.')
    category = models.ManyToManyField(MenuCategory, verbose_name='menu category', help_text='Category is the menu category that this menu item belongs to, i.e. \'Appetizers\'.')
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='order', help_text='The order is to specify the order in which items show up on the menu.')
    price = models.IntegerField(help_text='The price is the cost of the item.')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='menu', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='image', help_text='The image is an optional field that is associated with each menu item.')
    
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name='menu item'
        verbose_name_plural='menu items'
        ordering = ['classification', 'order', 'name']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py:**

```
from .models import Menu,MenuCategory
from django.views.generic import ListView

class MenuView(ListView):
    model= Menu
    conext_object_name='name'
    template_name = 'menu_list.html'
    queryset = Menu.objects.all()
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MenuView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Menucategory'] = MenuCategory.objects.all()
        context['Menus'] = self.queryset
        return context
```

**menu_list.html:**

```
<div>
{%for item in Menu%}
    <p>
        {{item.menu}}
        {{item.name}}
        {{item.additiona_text}}
        {{item.order}}
    </p>
    {%endfor%}
    {%for item in MenuCategory%}
    <p>
        {{item.name}}
        {{item.additiona_text}}
        {{item.order}}
    </p>
    {%endfor%}
</div>
```

when i browse localhost page after executing **runserver,** it shows only

> Django blog
>
> Breakfast 1
>
> Lunch 2
>
> Dinner 3

but my desired output should be:

> 1)Breakfast
>
> coffee
>
> Items
>
> 1 2 3
>
> Snacks Items 1 2 3
>
> 2)Lunch
>
> Starter items 1 2 3
>
> Main Courses Items 1 2 3

how can i get this structured table using plain bootstrap table row column where in every row column i will query the items with for loop? is their any other way? If there is alternative way, i am also interested....

Comment: Maybe you need recursivity to display the menu. If you have two loops, the it shows only the two deep levels of you menú

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your design is not good in the first place. If you want to display things in such a way, the logic would be the following:

- you have menu categories (breakfast, lunch, dinner...),
- you have menu items (coffee...) which belong to one or many menu categories,
- you have menus which belong to one category

So, your data structure should be the following:

```py
class MenuItem(models.Model):
    # [...]

class MenuCategory(models.Model):
    # [...]
    name = CharField...
    items = models.ManyToManyField(MenuItem)

class Menu(models.Model):
    # [...]
    menu_category = models.ForeignKey(MenuCategory)
```

Then, you could do what you want in your template (*note*: to name a queryset by its class name is a very bad practice. Just call it **menus**! That is what I'll do here) with a double `for` loop:

```html
<div>
{% for menu in menus %} 
    <h3>
        {{ menu.menu_category.name }}
    </h3>    
    <p>
        {%for item in menu.menu_category.items.all %}
            {{ item.name }}
        {% endfor %}
    </p>    
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Once again, your initial design is not the most appropriate in my opinion.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @rony01 glad to here that! :-) Do not hesitate to upvote the answer and choose it as  being the answer to your question so it can be closed.

Comment: i tried to upvote your comment, but my reputation is below 15 and may be that's why my vote is not countable...

Comment: You've got 19 now haha! But anyway this is not really important, it is just to close the topic. You can at least accept the answer I think, so it will close your question.

Comment: sorry for late...... little bit busy.... i did it already..... i am kinda new and start learning these things. sorry again for the late... and many many thanx for your answer

Comment: Hey @rony01! don't apologize, I'm also here to guide you. Happy coding! 